# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, devise, sendmail

When the user try to sign up, an email should be sent.
Working local.
There is **OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in Devise**  **SSL_read: wrong version number**

What's wrong ?

Ruby 2.1
Rails 3.2.12
Mac OS
Localhost

**environment.rb**

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
AdsPlatfrom::Application.initialize!
```

**development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.live.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'outlook.com',
    user_name:            'XXXXX',
    password:             'XXXXX',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

I have tried with `openssl_verify_mode: none`  nothing change

I have tried with the tlsmail gem, then deleted it since it has not worked and I am using ruby 2.1.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug in the mail gem.

The patch is outlined here: https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/659

Edit:
Here is how I made it work:

1. add the mail gem explicitly to your Gemfile

   `gem 'mail'`
2. Update the gem to its latest version (as of today should be 2.5.4)

   `bundle update --source mail`
3. Create `config/initializers/mail_patch.rb` and drop the contents this file in it https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexRevin/mail/a12f77d49c3957bddce3b76cf67587f76fa1acc9/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb

Alternatively you may reference your own branch of the gem. It seems like a cleaner solution too!

Comment: This does not work. It says that the problem is in line 112 of mail_patch. Actually, your answer seems to be copied from http://www.tagwith.com/question_1864741_opensslsslsslerror-in-devise/